Azure SQL Error - 'Resource ID : 2. The session limit for the database is xxx has been reached.'
I have an Microsoft Access application that uses an Azure SQL server. This has been running without any problems for many months.
Starting at the end of last week I'm getting the error:

ODBC Driver for SQL Server Resource ID : 2. The session limit for the database is xxx has been reached.

This stops all users of the database from being able to do anything.
I can see by using the sp_who proceedure in SQL Server Management studio that only some of the machines that the application is running on are generating large numbers of sessions that remain in a 'sleeping' state and are not being cleared.
Nothing in the application has changed recently and I assume that this has been caused by a Windows and/or Access update that was applied last week.
Any information about how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Connections are meant to be short-lived: created for the purpose of a query; execute the query (and handle its results); closed and disposed of thereafter. Is your Microsoft Access application's code closing and disposing of connections once it's done with them?

How old are the sleeping connections? Are the problem clients using the same ODBC driver version as the machines that don't have the issue? If you are using the "SQL Server" ODBC driver that ships with Windows instead of a separately installed SQL Server ODBC driver, be aware that Windows installs and maintains the legacy driver and an OS update could have introduced changes to connection pooling behavior.

Connections are not meant to be short lived. Connections are meant to live however long they need to live. Some applications work best in a chatty way, but that's far from efficient, especially for cloud based services where the connection setup can be magnitudes more work than the query being executed.

If the Access app is closed, it should close the connections. You'll need to check if the application instances open match the connections and get the last items the connection executed to get an idea of which area or what functionality is driving the behavior.

Thanks for your comments. I will investigate possible issues with the ODBC 18 driver and connection pooling.

This issue was fixed with the latest Office update (version 2408 - 17928.20156).
Thanks for the comments that were posted.
